# how to simulate a low-memory state when running a query

Tags: sql-server, database-internals

I am trying to better understand how SQL Server's execution engine behaves in a low-memory state.  Speaking in terms of memory grants, I am wondering if there is some way to force `GrantedMemory` to be equal to `RequiredMemory`.  (My guess is that there's an undocumented trace flag which will do that.  Does anyone know what it is?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server 2012 SP3 or better, you can use the `MAX_GRANT_PERCENT` hint to cap a single query's memory grant. However, you'd have to mess with the number to figure out which percent gives you the correct value (to force `GrantedMemory` to be equal to `RequiredMemory`).

See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3107401/new-query-memory-grant-options-are-available-min-grant-percent-and-max) for more details.

Prior to that, you'd have to use Resource Governor (Enterprise only though).