# Reducing Memory Pressure When Performing Parallel Staging Table Loads

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, partitioning, memory, bulk-insert

I'm attempting to migrate several very large tables in my data warehouse to new partition scheme (the older partition scheme was based on a `RANGE LEFT` function, that wasn't regularly split, and the most recent data is top-heavy in the last filegroup). The tables are sufficiently large (5 billion rows, 400 GB data space), that I'm leery to try a clustered index rebuild for fear of insufficient logging space.

I'm attempting to load the new table by running several `INSERT...(WITH TABLOCK) SELECT...WHERE <check constraint predicate> (OPTION MAXDOP 4)` statements into identical staging tables, one per filegroup in the scheme which I'll later switch into the replacement table. I coordinate execution of this faux bulk load by individual SSA jobs to take advantage of read-ahead/merry-go-round.

All works pretty well on the relatively small tables will all jobs running simultaneously. However, on the first large table, most of the SSA jobs have `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` waits while the job with the first partition is chugging along.

If my server has 768 GB RAM, 24 cores (hyperthreaded) and it's working on a 400 GB table, should I adjust my `MAXDOP` downward to free up more grants or enable resource governor to reduce the maximum grant to get more SSA jobs to kick in and work in parallel?

I initially tried the `BULK_LOGGED` recovery model, but went to `SIMPLE`. Transaction size is still huge; I generated over 1 TB of log copying 15 GB (must be due to the page splits if the data set wasn't sorted, I'm using page compression, and I was running other than `MAXDOP 1`).

I'm working on a FTDW rig (local SSD array running about 5 GB/s throughput, PureStorage array peaking at 11 GB/s) so hopefully disk latency won't be an issue. I'm writing the SSA jobs with SMO.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) 
    Oct 28 2016 18:17:30 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) 
      on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at my answer [over here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177601/how-to-simulate-a-low-memory-state-when-running-a-query/177604#177604), I mention a new(ish) query hint called `MAX_GRANT_PERCENT` that you can use to further control memory grants at the query level.

Documentation is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3107401/new-query-memory-grant-options-are-available-min-grant-percent-and-max).

Assuming queries are in the `default` pool and you haven't altered it, right now they can ask for 25% of your 768 GB of RAM. That's a lot of memory.

You'll have to play with reducing the percentage until you find a balance between concurrency and not spilling to disk-ency.

Hope this helps!